# Understanding 5 REQs to Router

Tags: scala, zeromq

Looking at the Scala [code](http://zguide.zeromq.org/scala:rtreq) for this `5 REQ <--> 1 ROUTER` setup:

### Worker

```
 class WorkerTask extends Runnable {
    override def run: Unit = {
      val rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis())
      val context = ZMQ.context(1)
      val worker = context.socket(ZMQ.REQ)
      worker.connect("tcp://localhost:5555")
      var total = 0
      var workload = ""

      do {
        worker.send("Ready".getBytes, 0)
        workload = new String(worker.recv(0))
        Thread.sleep (rand.nextInt(1) * 1000)
        total += 1
      } while (workload.equalsIgnoreCase("END") == false)
      printf("Completed: %d tasks\n", total)
    }
  }
```

### main (Router)

```
 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val NBR_WORKERS = 5
    val context = ZMQ.context(1)
    val client = context.socket(ZMQ.ROUTER)

    assert(client.getType > -1)
    client.bind("tcp://*:5555")
    val workers = List.fill(NBR_WORKERS)(new Thread(new WorkerTask))
    workers.foreach (_.start)

    for (i <- 1 to (NBR_WORKERS * 10)) {
      // LRU worker is next waiting in queue
      val address = client.recv(0)
      val empty = client.recv(0)
      val ready = client.recv(0)

      client.send(address, ZMQ.SNDMORE)
      client.send("".getBytes, ZMQ.SNDMORE)
      client.send("This is the workload".getBytes, 0)
    }

    for (i <- 1 to NBR_WORKERS) {
      val address = client.recv(0)
      val empty = client.recv(0)
      val ready = client.recv(0)

      client.send(address, ZMQ.SNDMORE)
      client.send("".getBytes, ZMQ.SNDMORE)
      client.send("END".getBytes, 0)
    }
  }
```

Running on my machine:

```
[info] Running net.server.RouterToReq
Completed: 21 tasks
Completed: 1 tasks
Completed: 27 tasks
Completed: 5 tasks
Completed: 1 tasks
```

As I partially understand the above code, 5 `REQ` workers accept requests from the `ROUTER` on port `5555`.

Lastly, in the following code:

```
 for (i <- 1 to NBR_WORKERS) {
      val address = client.recv(0)
      val empty   = client.recv(0)
      val ready   = client.recv(0)
```

What message is the `client`, i.e. `ROUTER`, receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worker sends the message "Ready" repeatedly as a single frame message.

The `REQ` socket will add a blank delimiter frame on the front.
The `ROUTER` socket will prepend an identifier frame to the front of any received message to identify where it came from.

Thus the single ready message becomes a 3 frame message when you receive it on the router, this is why 3 `recv` calls are required.

When you send on a router socket the first frame will be removed and used to identify which client to send the message to. The `REQ` socket will remove all frames until it finds an empty frame and thus you only need a single `recv` call on the worker side.

Comment: How does the `ROUTER` know the destination of each of the 5 `REQ`'s? Should their identities be set via: `context.setIdentity("WORKER" + i)` where `i` is an incrementing number?

Comment: ZeroMQ will assign a unique id to every client by default, but this will change between application runs.  So you don't need to use `setIdentity` unless you want persistence between runs so that a client can connect, send a request, disconnect, sometime later reconnect and get response to initial request.